# FragmentManager findFragmentById returns null on second time

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm adding a Fragment on the onCreate() method of my Activity. Then, I try access it using findFragmentByTag(). It works on the first time, but if I hit back to close my Activity and launch it again, findFragmentByTag() returns null.

In both cases the fragment is visually present in my activity. The onDestroy() method of the fragment is called when I close the Activity.

I have the same result using replace() instead of add(), and using findFragmentById() instead of findFragmentByTag().

**MyActivity.java**

```java
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        final MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // fm.getFragments() returns null
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "MyFragment")
            .commit();
    }

    private void onReceiveData() {
        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // fm.getFragments() returns an array with one null element (except on first try)
        final MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");
        // Fragment is null except during the first launch of MyActivity
    }
}
```

**MyFragment.java**

```java
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
}
```

**R.layout.activity_layout**

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Any idea why findFragmentByTag() only works the first time ?

Comment: when onReceiveData is called ??

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()

Comment: @AshishAgrawal It is called when I receive data from network. I call the request on onResume().

Comment: did you try replace in place of add fragment with addToBackStack

Comment: @AshishAgrawal Yes, as I said on my post.

Comment: @AmarbirSingh I tried that, but it doesn't change anything. The fragment IS added, cause I can see it on my screen.

Comment: @NolwennStephan why you declare your Bundle savedInstanceState to final....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. It was actually simple and had nothing to do with the code posted above.

It was caused by EventBus, which I use to call the `onReceiveData` method when I receive data from network. I forgot to unsubscribe from EventBus on my MyActivity `onDestroy` method, which was causing this weird behaviour.

Thanks anyway !